Did the king know he was giving such a powerful sword to Noor?
So the king gave to Noor the Black Blade, the only sword "Capable of withstanding any form of technique, skill and powers used upon without sustaining damage" for saving his daughter.
Did he know he was giving such a powerful sword to someone he just knew, or the extents of the sword powers were unknown to him?

What do you want to say by sword power

I think he doesn't know all power that this blade had because it is say that he used it when was an adventurer but I don't think he knew all the power of the blade if not he won't give it easily as you see the resistance of the blade
